# Build 64 bit static library

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, mingw-w64

I want to build static library, that will be used with 64bit Qt Creator. I can build this lib(freetype) on Windows, or Mac, it doesn't matter. On Windows I've found mingw-64 and here is a question- is it neccessary to have 64bit version of make(for makefiles) from mingw64, or there is some way to just swap mingw32-g++ with 64bit version, and use old make from mingw32? Am I misunderstanding sth? I've already built 32bit version of freetype.a and it works fine on ubuntu and windows, where I have 32bit Qt Creator(and for Mac there is only 64bit Qt Creator, I don't know why...)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `make` system doesn't care whether `mingw` is 32 or 64 bit. All it cares is that it can call off to the program. If you can run these programs from a command line, so can `make`.

Comment: but how to show make which version of g++/c++(don't know the difference) use?

Comment: because I renamed old mingw32-g++ etc., and even with that, make created lib successfully, so I guess it has compiler built-in...

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Are you asking how to specify the version that make uses, or how to autodetect the platform, or how to ask the compiler which version it is?

Comment: how to specify version(32/64) that make uses.

Comment: Usually gcc / mingw / whatever have both a short name (gcc) and a long name (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc). Using the short name you risk invoking the wrong one. Just have `make` call off to the long name.

Comment: but HOW to do that? I didn't find any option where you can specify it.

Comment: That's the executable name. You don't specify it, you just run it. And as for your make system, there are usually 3 routes. In an automake system, it will automatically detect the right compiler for you. In a regular make system, it will either directly call `gcc` or it will use the `$CC` environment variable. If it's calling `gcc`, just replace `gcc` with the compiler you want. If it's `$CC`, before you run make, run `export CC=your_gcc_here`.

Comment: even that I've renamed all gcc etc. it works, and `$CC` isn't set(so it is kinda of weird).but I'll try to set $CC

Comment: first- make uses ar.exe; second- after changing ar.exe to one from mingw64, it creates the same file as earlier...

Comment: @Mackiekp: I don't know what you're compiling. If it's calling off to `ar`, it's probably a static library. However `ar` is basically a glorified `zip` program, so I doubt that's your problem.

Comment: because that's what I want to build- static library.

Comment: @Mackiekp: you're not giving me much to work with here. I'm debugging totally blind here. Tell me more about the makefile, the environment, the project, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to build statically linked library of http://freetype.sourceforge.net/index2.html , that will be linked to Qt Creator' desktop project. I've build 32bit version of it, but it doesn't work with Qt Creator for mac os x(error: `"file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)"`), which needs 64bit version. Makefile used to build this lib: http://pastebin.com/utnsCega. I've downloaded mingw-w64-bin_i686, and replaced mingw32 ar.exe file,but it builds exactly the same file(==size is the same;I've checked one, and it errored me like before).